# I have used stack (stl) to find the intersection point of the two linked list ,but I am getting segmentation fault, below is my function,

Tags: c++, linked-list, stl, stack, intersection

All headers files are included and I have to return the data of the node where intersection is found

```
int findMergeNode(SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, SinglyLinkedListNode* head2){
    
    stack<int>s1;
    stack<int>s2;
    int ans;
    while(head1!=NULL)
    {
        int x=head1->data;
        s1.push(x);
        head1=head1->next;
    }
    while(head2!=NULL)
    {
        int x=head2->data;
        s2.push(x);
        head2=head2->next;
    }
    while(s1.top()==s2.top())
    {
        ans=s1.top();
        s1.pop();
        s2.pop();
    }
    
    return ans;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At least this while loop

```
while(s1.top()==s2.top())
{
    ans=s1.top();
    s1.pop();
    s2.pop();
}
```

can invoke undefined behavior because you are not checking whether one of the stacks is already empty.

Moreover as initially the variable `ans` is not initialized the function can return an indeterminate value.

Pay attention to that as the lists themselves are not changed in the function then the function should be declared like

```
int findMergeNode( const SinglyLinkedListNode* head1, const SinglyLinkedListNode* head2 );
```